# Why does the base-emitter voltage in NPN transistor become constant?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, semiconductors

[image: schematic]

The setup above shows the experiment that I have been working with. During the experiment, the current \$i_c\$ and the voltage \$V_{be}\$ were measured for increasing \$V_{in}\$. At some point, the current through the collector will be constant, due to the barrier in the forward-biased base-emitter region being lowered as much as possible by \$V_{in}\$, meaning that its maximum value follows Ohm’s law.

As we further increase \$V_{in}\$, we will find that \$V_{be}\$ will go towards a constant value. Why is that? Shouldn’t it increase too? I have great trouble understanding this last part.

I will appreciate any help!

EDIT: The polarity on the \$V_{in}\$ is wrong. My mistake.

Comment: It depends series R. To Vbe as a saturated diode with a small bulk resistance.

Comment: It will always increase with increasing current.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Then why do I find a nearly constant value when increasing the input voltage?

Comment: “Nearly” is the key, also you’re self heating the junction which slightly reduces the voltage for a given forward current.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I guess that makes sense. I just wonder where the nearly constant behavior comes from, i.e. why the voltage seems to converge for increasing input voltage.

Comment: A transistor is a Current driven device, If you looked at the current ratio from Base/Emitter  to Collector/Emitter is would explain what was going on much better. For the input signal you show, any value of Vin less than about 0.5V results in almost no C/E current. This is why a transistor used as an amplifier is usually biased to some operating point to allow a linear gain for the signal.

Comment: Vin is the wrong polarity, assuming NPN.

Comment: @Chu Not very helpful

Comment: @pjHart1000 Just an observation. A comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base-emitter voltage generally follows the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling) with some series resistance. There is a small effect from the collector current.

The ideal diode portion of the voltage approximately increases proportional with the logarithm of the ratio of current to a constant(the “saturation current”). A 10:1 increase in current only results in about 60mV of increase, as shown in the linked Wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

Simple!

Because the b-e terminals technically have a diode in between them and this diode has the voltage-current characteristics as a regular one.

[image]

[Source: Wikipedia article "Bipolar Junction Transistor"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor)

Answer (score 0):

The standard diode math has the behavior of: 2:1 more current causes only 0.018 volts more forward voltage drop. This 0.018 volts is very predictable (set by doping profiles) across nanoamps to milliAmps. And perhaps picomps to milliamps.

This is a logarithmic behavior; it is NOT a constant voltage, just a log behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the schematic as drawn, Vbe will plateau around -5V, the "reverse breakdown voltage" of a typical transistor, where the base-emitter junction breaks down like a zener diode ... another device typically used for generating a roughly constant voltage.

If the polarity of the source Vin is unintentional, refer to the other answers instead.